# Pandas: assign value depending on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have to dataframes that look like this:

```
 df1:          condition        
               A               
               A              
               A               
               B              
               B             
               B           
               B   

 df2:          condition      value   
               A               1
               B               2
```

I would like to assign to each condition its value, adding a column to df1 in order to obtain:

```
 df1:          condition     value      
               A               1
               A               1
               A               1
               B               2
               B               2
               B               2
               B               2
```

how can I do this? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) if need append one column only:

```
df1['value'] = df1['condition'].map(df2.set_index('condition')['value'])

print (df1)
  condition  value
0         A      1
1         A      1
2         A      1
3         B      2
4         B      2
5         B      2
6         B      2
```

Or use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join if `df2` have more columns:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='condition', how='left')
print (df)
  condition  value
0         A      1
1         A      1
2         A      1
3         B      2
4         B      2
5         B      2
6         B      2
```

Comment: Merge is definitely the way to go.