# Add column from dataframe to another dataframe if some condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1

| ASSET | PRICE |
| --- | --- |
| BTC | 50000 |
| ETH | 4000 |
| ADA | 3 |
| XRP | 1 |

df2

| ASSET | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| BTC | 1 |
| ETH | 10 |
| ADA | 100 |
| SOL | 50 |
| XRP | 40 |
| BNB | 200 |

Given these 2 dataframes I would like to add the amount column from df2 to df1 only if the asset is the same.
End result for df1 would need to be (only keep assets in df1):

df1

| ASSET | PRICE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BTC | 50000 | 1 |
| ETH | 4000 | 10 |
| ADA | 3 | 100 |
| XRP | 1 | 40 |

Comment: This operation is called [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) -> `df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='ASSET', how='left')` (See [left merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645883/15497888))

Comment: Or with [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) -> `df1['AMOUNT'] = df1['ASSET'].map(df2.set_index('ASSET')['AMOUNT'])` (See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52703621/15497888))