# Combine two dataframes according to common values

Tags: pandas, indexing, merge

I have two pandas dataframe Df1 where the first indicate the coordinates of an animal position over a certain space:

```
Lat       Lon
49.3594   67.8962
49.5978   67.2584
49.5782   67.2648
49.5687   67.9431
```

The second dataframe Df2 indicate the different depths of the study area according to coordinates

```
Lat       Lon           Depth
49.2587   67.2584       3.0
49.5978   67.2584       6.0
49.5687   67.2648       5.0
49.5782   67.9431       9.0
```

What i want to do is to combine the depths of my second dataframe Df2 to the coordinates of the Df1 to reveal the depth at which the animal spent most of its time.

Here is the code that I tried to do:

```
# join the columns Lat and Lon in order to have the coordinates for each point

Df1['LatLon'] = Df1['Lat'].astype(str) + Df1['Lon'].astype(str)
Df2['LatLon'] = Df2['Lat'].astype(str) + Df2['Lon'].astype(str)

# according to the answer found in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703597/pandas-assign-value-depending-on-another-dataframe#:~:text=df1%20%5B%27value%27%5D%20%3D%20df1%20%5B%27condition%27%5D.map%20%28df2.set_index%20%28%27condition%27%29%20%5B%27value%27%5D%29,B%202%205%20B%202%206%20B%202][1] 
# i applied this line of code to assign values of depth found on Df2 to my Df1


Df1['Depth'] = Df1['LatLon'].map(Df2.set_index('LatLon')['Depth'])
```

However, the following error message appears:

```
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't create a combined key and `map`, just `merge` on Lat and Lon. If you have duplicated combinations of Lat/Lon, decide if you want combinations of rows or if you need to aggregate